# Disable automatic switching of run destination when changing scheme in Xcode

Tags: xcode

One of the recent versions of Xcode added a feature: when you select a scheme, Xcode changes the run destination (i.e., the target device) to the one that was last used with the scheme you selected:

[image]

I find this feature annoying, after having spent months with it I still get tripped up by it. Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this?